# Can't scrape hidden data from a website with request

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scape data from this [website](https://mangadex.org/titles/latest) using requests but got the html with this div being hidden

```
<body>
    <div id="__nuxt"></div> //this is the div that has hidden data
    <script>...</script>
</body>
```

My code was

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://mangadex.org/titles/latest')
print(response.text)
```

I then tried requests-html, a library that shows hidden html rendered with javascript

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://mangadex.org/titles/latest')
response.html.render()
print(response.text)
```

But it's still the same.

Comment: This is not "hidden HTML".  This is a dynamic website, where the HTML is generated by Javascript code.  `requests_html` can do that, although the `text` variable still has the page as delivered.  You should try the `find` APIs to find the section you want.

Comment: @TimRoberts it still doesn't work. I tried `a = response.html.find('a', first=True)` (find by element 'a') and `a = response.html.find('_chapter-feed__title', first=True)` (find by class 'chapter-feed__title') but it didn't work. 
The only thing that worked is `a = response.html.find('div', first=True)` which still has no content inside it printed

Comment: Well, the next step is to try Selenium, but it should be the same as requests_html.

Comment: @TimRoberts i got my problem solved! but selenium also worked. i can get the full html when i opened chrome with selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) said, this isn't "hidden data", it's Javascript, which is querying their API (if you open up the Network inspector of your browser, and click to the next page of their site, you can see the JSON files being downloaded!).

Although you could scrape the JSON files this way, it's going to be infinitely easier to just use their API directly. [The documentation for it is here](https://api.mangadex.org/docs/).

Comment: I figured it out! Im aware of the api long ago and thought that it had everything i need except the lastest chapter updates. but as i opened Network as u said, i accidentally found where the page fetch the list of new chapters from. so it accidentally solved my problem!